# How can I pull in the most recent blog posts to a section with Elementor Page Builder?

Tags: plugins

My client has requested I build the site with Elemental Page Builder, so I am having some trouble adding the 3 most recent blog posts to a section on the home page. I'd much rather prefer to just use a custom query and loop through but I have to do it with this page builder.

I've created a template, which pulls in the 3 most recent blog posts in a 3 column layout, but when I try to insert the shortcode for this template into a section on the home page, it only brings in one blog post from the archive with no featured image.

Anybody have suggestions or a guide they can point me to?

Comment: Can you share code you have  added for shortcode

Answer (score 0):

is the home page template from the theme or built using Elementor?

If its the themes own home page template and you are adding the Elementor Template shortcode to the php file, then the resources it needs may not be getting loaded.

Those Elementor template shortcodes work best when they are inserted into a page build using Elementor.

if you are adding them within a page designed using Elementor, are you using the Elementor Shortcode widget or trying to add them to say a Text Editor or Header widget?